# Dell SNMP enterprise MIB returns no data - PowerEdge R720xd

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, snmp

I have a Ubuntu Dell server that returns no SNMP Data for MIB `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises`.

Has anyone have any idea on how to troubleshoot this? I've spent quite a time and yet haven't fixed. I've searched through Dell forums for similar issue but with no proper answer.

The BIOS, Firmware, OMSA are all latest version...

I've enabled DataEng and started all the OMSA services. But when I run `snmpwalk ... 20.20.20.20 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises` it returns no data (When I say no data, it returns `UCD-SNMP-MIB` and other `NET-SNMP` stuff but it doesn't return any `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises` like it does for windows as shown below). If I try a specific Enterprise OID then it returns empty.

Note that other MIB's work fine as well. For example `snmpwalk ... 20.20.20.20 sysDescr` works.

I've also verified that smbios returns data as excepted. (It was returning error before and DataEng service wasn't starting but it got fixed after a reboot`

`/usr/sbin/smbios-sys-info-lite` output:

```
Libsmbios:    2.4.1
System ID:    0x0528
Service Tag:  xyzxyz
Express Service Code: 123456789
Asset Tag:  Not Specified
Product Name: PowerEdge R720xd
BIOS Version: 2.9.0
Vendor:       Dell Inc.
Is Dell:      1
OEM String 1: Dell System
OEM String 2: 5[0000]
OEM String 3: 17[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]
OEM String 4: 17[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]
OEM String 5: 17[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]
OEM String 6: 17[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]
```

Other Windows Dell servers return data for SNMP enterprises as shown below:

```
root@hostname:~/root# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public -OQ 10.10.10.10 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises 
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.77.1.1.1.0 = "6"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.77.1.1.2.0 = "3"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.77.1.1.3.0 = "01 00 00 00 "
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.77.1.1.4.0 = 1234564789
....
```